# What's the best NAME for a NAMELESS Category you add at the top of a .m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

So the other day I was sick of typing out repetetive addTarget:action:forControlEvents:s, and macros are only entertaining for so long, so I did this:

```
@implementation UIControl (xx)
-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
 {
 [self addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
@end
```

**and simply added it at the top of the .m file in question.**

**Works great of course, but notice the "xx".**

***What's the best thing to NAME a "nameless" Category like this?***

Note that it really ***NEEDS NO NAME as the name will never be used ANYWHERE. The best thing would be to give it no name*** - but syntactically you cannot leave that blank.

(If you leave the xx blank - it becomes an "Extension" which is quite different.)

I was thinking maybe:

- a single underscore
- the name of the class again identically
- "quick"
- perhaps the name of the class in this file (as in "quick extra routines for UIControl in CherryBomb") - so it would be UIControl(CherryBomb), i.e., to remind you that these extra routines are handy for CherryBomb and are indeed in the file CherryBomb.m
- "x"
- your or your company's initials (use the same "quick" Category name everywhere)
- "ThisTextNeverUsedAnywhere"

(By the way ... it appears you *do not* actually need to include an interface for such a Category, i.e. you can omit...

```
//you can actually get away without these lines...
//#import <UIKit/UIControl.h>
//@interface  UIControl (x)
//-(void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
//@end
```

... that part and it works fine.)

For people who love Categories, and who doesn't, what's the answer to this troubling question?

What should you name a "nameless" Category ***where the name is never going to be used again and is irrelevant***, because the text is typed directly only in the top of one .m file for use only in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use `Private`. Because they are, well, private... I'd love to hear people's thoughts on that though. :)

Comment: I'd like to know why this answer was voted down. All of my private method declarations (i.e., `@interface Foo(Private)`) use `Private`. If that's wrong or there's a good reason why I should use something else, it'd be very helpful to know! Thanks. :)

Comment: I agree. :) More seriously, it's succinct and descriptive, and I didn't see a reason to name it something else. It's not like these private methods need to be exposed anywhere, even if the code was open-sourced. I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Heh, awesome! Never received a bounty before, still pretty new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: i especially liked that it bumped me above 1500 points, letting me create my own tags. :) i'm glad this "cowboy" method works for you guys, heh

Answer (score 3):

An [Extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) is the same as a Category *except* the extra methods must go into the same implementation as the original class.

This is useful for adding private methods to a class that don't need to be exposed in the header file, or redeclaring @properties.

Obviously, this can't be used when adding Categories to classes that you don't have the source for. e.g. 
UIControl

As for how I name Categories: I use my Three Letter Prefix and the word "Extensions" such as:

```
UIControl (ADNExtensions)
```

Comment: Yes. But it's more than just hiding the methods. If a method is not in a public header it's conventional to treat it as a private method and not use it outside of the class. It's a way of keeping the public interface of your objects clean.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with `_`.

Comment: Well, it's standing in for "blank": the point here is there's no need at all for ANY name, since it's only used locally. **Blank would be best (but not possible)** - given that that is the case, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I like the naming convention "UIControl+MyClassName" for something like that, and naming categories that add to system classes generally as "UIControl+MyPurpose".

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I use the original class name plus a brief description of intent.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a quick, off-the-cuff category, then I'll call it something like `DDAdditions`.  If it's supposed to be a bit more formal, then I'll figure out what the defining purpose of the category is and construct a name off that.

**edit** more information:

Here's what I do:

When I name the file that contains the category, it is always of the form:

```
BaseClass+CategoryName.h/m
```

So if I have a `UIButton` category called `FooBar`, the name of the file is `UIButton+FooBar.h/m`.  Seeing this construct in my source tree instantly tells me 2 (potentially 3) things:

1. That I'm extending a class
2. What class I'm extending
3. What the purpose of the extensions is (if the category name is descriptive enough)

If I'm declaring multiple categories in a single file, then the "BaseClass" bit can vary depending on how the extended classes are related.

1. If there's a mutable-immutable relation (ie, I'm extending both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` with a category that offers both immutable and mutable variants [ex: `-[NSArray shuffledArray]` and `-[NSMutableArray shuffle]`]), then I'll simply use `NSArray` as the base class.
2. If there's a kind relation (the things I'm extending are both collections), then I'll try and come up with a base name that reflects that relation, like `Collections+CategoryName.h/m`.
3. If I can't come up with a way that the categories are related, then they shouldn't be in the same file.  Using a single file for "the categories that just add little things here and there with no defining purpose" is (in my opinion) wrong.  File names, like method names, should reflect the purpose of the file.

Coming up with a proper category name takes practice.  If I'm in a hurry or am just adding a category to try something out, I'll use "DDAdditions" (my initials + "Additions").  If I'm using a category to hide methods on a class, I'll go with something like "Private" or "Internal".

Otherwise, I find the purpose of these methods and construct a name out of that.

For example, if I'm adding a method to `NSDictionary` to take its key-value pairs and URL encode them as a query string, then I'll call the category `DDURLAdditions` or `DDURLEncoding` or something like that.

The over-arching principle here is to be descriptive.  Really it doesn't matter what you call your category or what you name your file as long as its clear what they are.  (One of the things we love about Objective-C is that its verbosity makes it largely self-documenting)  The only other thing to watch out for is to make sure that your category doesn't have the same name as another category for that same class.  (and also that your method names don't conflict, etc)

Comment: @Joe under certain circumstances you *can* leave it blank.  That's called a Class Extension.  Otherwise, call it whatever you want.

Comment: A class extension doesn't have to be in the original file, but a class extension can only be declared as an @interface, not an @implementation. I often use class extension to declare private methods I want to be able to see from other classes...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with categories is that the compiler and the linker NEED the name of the category to be able to differentiate your symbols or else it can't find the symbols and build your class properly. So call it "Private", or "Additions", or "Convenience" but in any case you'll need a name, and if you happen to have two categories of that type for the same class in different files I advise you to find different names, or better yet: Follow Dave's suggestion.

Note, the name could have been removed for class extension simply because they're only interfaces, it was easy to instruct the compiler to ignore the category name and simply add the methods to the main class block as temporary declaration and thus put a warning inside the @implementation when the methods aren't implemented.

Whereas for a category you needn't to have an @interface matching an @implementation or vice-versa: @interface would contain only declarations that you don't necessarily need to implement (however, don't try to call them if they aren't actually implemented you'll get a crash...). And if you put the @implementation alone without @interface before where you use, the compiler will have stored the method declarations and thus removed the "might not respond to selector" warning.

Note: you can also write an Xcode macro to build your "convenience" category directly...

Comment: Psycho ... "the compiler and the linker NEED the name of the category" - that is a **fantastic point**, thanks!  Good one.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer categories to be named after what they do. In the example you gave, I would call it "UIControl+Convenience" or "UIControl+Targets". KWTargets or JBTargets is also fine. Most of your examples tell you little or nothing about what the category does, which is confusing when you try to understand unfamiliar code (either because someone else wrote it, or because you haven't looked at it in a while).